# How to put image into jQuery Cycle2 slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

How can I put image in pager active cycle? Sample is on the uploaded picture below.

[image: pager with ring active slide]

It's a usual cycle2 slider, but instead a dot in pager i want a ring, which i sliced from a psd.

Comment: <div class="cycle-slideshow"
                    data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz
                    data-cycle-timeout=2000
                    data-cycle-pager-event="mouseover"
                    >
                    <div class="cycle-pager"></div>
                    <img src="image/carousel2.png"/> 
                    <img src="image/carousel4.png" /> 
                    <img src="image/carouselPic.png"/>
                    <img src="image/carousel3.png"/> 
                    <img src="image/carousel5.png"> 
 
                </div>  <!-- end cycle-slideshow -->

Comment: dont post it in a comment, update your question